# Why does Derby have to be manually added even though its apart of JDK

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, derby

A little while ago I asked a question about a no driver error. I was able to figure it out by adding the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\db\lib directory to my eclipse project manually. I'm just wondering why it does. Especially when it seems like all of the other jar files in JDK 8 run automatically. Maybe.

Comment: The database delivered using JDK was JavaDB. Derby is an Apache fork of JavaDB. Due to heavy adoption of Derby Oracle removed JavaDB from JDK. To load a driver class you have to use the DriverManager.

Comment: It may be part of the JDK, but it is not part of Java itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are correct that you need to add the Driver JAR file to your classpath.  The Oracle documentation for JavaDB says so: see http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/getstart/twwdactivity4.html for example.

Why?  Well this is conjecture, but suppose that you wanted to run a Java program that talked to a MySQL database.  If the JAR files containing the Derby drivers were added to the JVM's bootstrap classpath automatically, then the Derby `Driver` classes would typically be loaded (by the `DriverManager` framework), even though it is only the MySQL `Driver` class that you want to use.  Many people would consider loading unwanted drivers to be a *defect* ... if the JVM did that.

Comment: Even if the JAR file with derby db is add to JVM bootstrap classpath, it still doesn't stop the user from adding additional drivers for other db. And the JDBC connection string will decide which DB to connect when required. With this behavior being the default I do not understand why derby **should** not be added to JVM bootstrap classpath (except may be to reduce unnecessary JARs in classpath when it is not being used).

Comment: Suppose that an application uses the JDBC `DriverManager` approach.  That will cause all of the available drivers to be loaded.  But if the application doesn't want to use either of the Derby drivers (to talk to MySQL!) ... you have now loaded a bunch of code unnecessarily.  A lot of people would call that a **defect**.

Comment: Consider adding that to your answer .